# A proper way to convert 2D Array into RGB or GrayScale image for precision difference

Tags: image, conv-neural-network, precision, rgb, grayscale

I have a 2D CNN model where I perform a classification task. My images are all coming from a sensor data after conversion.

So, normally, my way is to convert them into images using the following approach

```
newsize = (9, 1000)
pic = acc_normalized[0]
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(pic*255), 'L')
img = img.resize(newsize)
image_path = "Images_Accel"
image_name = "D1." + str(2)
img.save(f"{image_path}/{image_name}.jpeg")
```

This is what I obtain:

[image]

However, their precision is sort of important. For instance, some of the numerical values are like:

117.79348187327987 or 117.76568758022673.

As you see in the above line, their difference is the digits, when I use uint8, it only takes 117 to when converting it into image pixels and it looks the same, right? But, I'd like to make them different. In some cases, the difference is even at the 8th or 10th digit.

So, when I try to use mode F and save them .jpeg in Image.fromarray line it gives me error and says that PIL cannot write mode F to jpeg.

Then, I tried to first convert them RGB like following;

```
img = Image.fromarray(pic, 'RGB')
```

I am not including np.float32 just before pic or not multiplying it by 255 as it is. Then, I convert this image to grayscale. This is what I got for RGB image;

[image: RGB Image]

After converting RGB into grayscale:

[image]

As you see, it seems that there is a critical different between the first pic and the last pic. So, what should be the proper way to use them in 2D CNN classification? or, should I convert them into RGB and choose grayscale in CNN implementation and a channel of 1? My image dimensions 1000x9. I can even change this dimension like 250x36 or 100x90. It doesn't matter too much. By the way, in the CNN network, I am able to get more than 90% test accuracy when I use the first-type of image.

The main problem here is using which image conversion method I'll be able to take into account those precision differences across the pixels. Would you give me some idea?

---- EDIT -----

Using .tiff format I made some quick comparisons.

First of all, my data looks like the following;

[image]

So, if I convert this first reading into an image using the following code where I use np.float64 and L gives me a grayscale image;

```
newsize = (9, 1000)
pic = acc_normalized[0]
img = Image.fromarray(np.float64(pic), 'L')
img = img.resize(newsize)
image_path = "Images_Accel"
image_name = "D1." + str(2)
img.save(f"{image_path}/{image_name}.tiff")
```

It gives me this image;

[image]

Then, the first 15x9 matrix seems like following image; The contradiction is that if you take a closer look at the numerical array, for instance (1,4) member, it's a complete black where the numerical array is equal to 0.4326132099074307. For grayscale images, black means that it's close to 0 cause it makes white if it's close to 1. However, if it's making a row operation, there is another value closer to 0 and I was expecting to see it black at (1,5) location. If it does a column operation, there is again something wrong. As I said, this data has been already normalized and varies within 0 and 1. So, what's the logic that it converts the array into an image? What kind of operation it does?

[image]

Secondly, if I first get an RGB image of the data and then convert it into a grayscale image, why I am not having exactly the same image as what I obtained first? Should the image coming from direct grayscale conversion (L method, np.float64) and the one coming from RGB-based (first I get RGB then convert it to grayscale) be the same? There is a difference in black-white pixels in those images. I do not know why we have it.

[image]

---- EDIT 2 ----

.tiff image with F mode and np.float32 gives the following;

[image]

Comment: so your sensor is giving you images in RGB with floating point precision?...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but you seem to want to store image differences that are less than 1, i.e. less than the resolution of integer values.

To do so, you need to use an image format that can store floats. JPEG, PNG, GIF, TGA and BMP cannot store floats. Instead, use TIFF, EXR or PFM formats which can handle floats.

---

Alternatively, you can create 16-bit PNG images wherein each pixel can store values in range 0..65535. So, say the maximum difference you wanted to store was 60 you could calculate the difference and multiply it by 1000 and round it to make an integer in range 0..60000 and store as 16-bit PNG.

You could record the scale factor as a comment within the image if it is variable.

Comment: I have a sensor reading which gives me numerical readings in array format. Then, I need to convert them into images to be able to feed the 2D CNN. However, those sensor readings are precision sensitive, which means that the difference between the sensor readings can be resulting from the number of digits or precision. For examples, one of the readings can be 0.1145899 and another one 0.1145865, as you see, the difference between them is the last two digits.

Comment: I was using np.uint8 and multiplying them by 255 and L gives me grayscale images, however, I do not believe that this is the correct way to convert them into images since it does not reflect the difference in precisions. What you suggest is that I can store them in TIFF, EXR or PFM format to be able to get this sensitivity in image pixels, right?

Comment: By the way, I normalize the data before I convert them into images, so all the numerical values varies between 0 and 1, i.e. 0.51894879, 0.51894807, .... so they have -let's say- 8 digits, I'd like to see that difference in the last two digit after converting into images in the pixels.  Based on your response, the way could be either store them in TIFF or multiplying them by a really huge number to catch a reasonable difference in those arrays as in the integer form.

Comment: TIFF supports 32-bit floats (single precision) and 64-bit floats (double precision).

Comment: I updated my question using your approach, there is still a confusion over how TIFF format store it. Can you please quickly take a look at what I edited?

Comment: Your code is saving as JPEG still. I still can't see through all the material in your question to know what you are really trying to do or what the issue is. I think you have RGB888 input images in range 0..255 and you want to normalize some differences and maybe save something in range 0..1, but I don't understand the issue at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, it was .tiff my original code, I am just using that format now to store them. The issue is why this value at (1,4) location 0.4326132099074307 is black and 0.37650988241180894 this value is not black at (1,5) location. The second issue is that why there is a difference between grayscale images in the last two pictures. One comes from a direct conversion and the other comes from the first RGB to grayscale conversion.

Comment: Try changing `np.float64(...)` to `np.float()` (or float32) as **PIL** doesn't support float64 although TIFF itself does.

Comment: I added EDIT-2 section in my question to see what the image looks like, based on https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes, it seems that I need to use mode F instead of L with np.float32, then I am getting a uniform grayscale distribution across the image as I was expecting, this is making more sense.

Comment: Then, in the case of using RGB, I feel that I need to multiply it by 255 since RGB use 3x8 bit pixes and 8-bit pixel has a range of 0-255. But, it's not going to account for the floating part, it only considers the integer part, right?

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to suddenly get RGB data from greyscale data. I don't understand why you now want to go to 8-bit when you are interested in the 8th decimal place? 8-bit data is integer... it doesn't have fractional/decimal parts.